# Getting started with Orleans: Implementation, Hosting, and Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, actor, orleans

#### I'm making an app as a learning experience, and I've run into two major issues:

1) I have an implementation that may or may not be a good idea for Orleans...I just don't know.

2) I'm looking for advice on hosting and deployment, basically: where and how? This is just a learning experience, so small and cheap/free is important.

#### So, to start... A little info on the app I'm making:

- It's a mobile gps based app with MongoDB storage.
- The real world is divided up into distinct and persistent regions, blocks of gps locations.
- When a user is active in a given region, he becomes visible to every other user in the region, and he begins receiving updates about the region's properties and the locations of other users active in the region.
- The user can manipulate the properties of the region.
- Users need to be able to explicitly join and leave regions, but also leave after some time-out.

#### I have two grains for this: *UserGrain* and *RegionGrain*.

For **issue 1)** Is it even a good idea to implement the Region as a grain? A few different samples support this implementation. But, the best practices manual suggests it wouldn't be a good idea, since it is a long-running job (the Region persists indefinitely), and this type of grain could be a bottleneck.  But... I need it to act like the "GameGrain" from the "Presence" sample, that players join and leave (explicitly or timing out).

For **issue 2)**

- I have a silo implemented as a console app.  I've used amazon elastic beanstalk to deploy a .net web app, but I don't know where to start with a console app. Is amazon a good choice at all? I just defaulted to it from recent usage.
- If the RegionGrain is a bad idea... what might a good idea look like?
- If the RegionGrain is a good idea... is there a way to tell Orleans to just never deactivate it?  If so, I should use Timers for the time-out requirement, and the presence and heartbeat for updates...right?  If not, should I just host another console app somewhere that maintains and runs RegionGrain(s)?

Answer (score 3):

If this is still an actual question:

On **Issue 1)** - Your region grain seems fine to me - it's not a constantly working grain but it's your region registry: when user enters the region - he registers in the region grain (or being registered by an external region monitor if you want to remove user responsibility around this). Such regions can persists indefinitely, but this doesn't mean they are long running jobs.

**Long running job** in orleans terminology is the one that is doing a lot of active work in a single method (or worse - sleeps for seconds or minutes) - this will hold the grain and thread from orleans thread pool - so such practice is considered bad but it's not really applicable here.

**On hosting** - Amazon is as good as any other hosting as long as you know how to host and run your work there. We are using Azure for our hosting - Cloud Service is very easy to start with and VM cost is usually on par with Amazon (except Azure free trial is shorter than Amazon 3.months vs 1.year but with more resources).

**On Issue 2), timers and other** - timers are not persistent so if the grain is deactivated - they are lost and have to be restarted. Reminders are better option to revive grain, as well as there is a method on a grain which allows you to prevent deactivation - `DelayDeactivation()`, the opposite one for explicit deactivation is `DeactivateOnIdle()`. 
Regarding the updates - we found that Orleans Streams are very nice concept to broadcast mass updates (e.g. from RegionGrain to all subscribed\registered users) so take a look on it and it may solve many questions with subscription and broadcasting.

In general, I'd build this a bit differently - make your system reactive instead of pulsing\proactive. e.g.:

- User enters the region - so he just registering his presence on the region grain and subscribes for region events.
- Any changes to the region are recorded and pushed to Orleans stream - so all subscribers will receive region event.
- Any changes to other players - messaged to region grain (so it'll be our source of truth) and then re-broadcasted to other region subscribers.

In case of issues with very noisy regions (when too many changes are happening in the system and too big re-broadcasts - you can make your region just an another subscriber to the region stream - so every player will broadcast to every other via Orleans Stream and to region itself. OR make your region into a broadcast controller which would broadcast all changes in one batch to the stream only after a certain period of time - every second or every 5 seconds...

Hope this helps.